# Is MS office 64 bit compatible with Delphi 6 applications?

Tags: delphi, ms-word, typelib, delphi-6, tlb

My application is developed in Delphi 6, The application have some document management modules which works fine with 32 bit MS word, but not with 64 bit MS Word.

A type library called WORD_TLB is used to access the MS word functions from delphi code. Can i generate a new type library or something else to make the application work with 64 bit MS word? Is it even possible for a Delphi 6 application to work with MS WORD 64 bit?

Please suggest.

Comment: If you have a stand alone 32-bit program that manages 64-bit Office with a moral equivalent of `CreateObject`, that *should* work. If you have an add-in for Office, you need to recompile it as 64-bit.

Comment: Its a type library, kind of an add in component. I will try recompiling it. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it even possible for a Delphi 6 application to work with MS WORD 64 bit?

Yes, it is possible to automate 64 bit Office applications from a 32 bit Delphi process. The Office applications execute as out of process COM servers and so the mismatch of bitness is not an issue.

I'm sure that you do have a problem, but that problem is not due to trying to automate 64 bit out of process COM servers from a 32 bit process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Do i need to generate a 64 bit TLB file and replace it with the 32 bit TLB(WORD_TLB.pas) ? And i have to recompile all the modules associated with the TLB right?

Comment: No. You should not even need to recompile. You need to debug your program and decisively identify the cause of the fault. At the moment you are guessing.